# SSRS Category grouping for one big pie

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, grouping, pie-chart, ssrs-2008-r2

Dataset:

[image]

This is the dataset I am having an issue with. I expect to have more as time goes on so the solution will have to be dynamic. As you can see, the City is exactly the same, but when I put it into my pie chart I get this:

[image]

I've looked for over two hours now as to how to combine these two wedges to get one big pie, but `=sum(Fields!Quantity.value)` will not do it in the values or the Category Groups areas on the chart. What would the expression be, and would it go in the values area or the Category Groups area under Chart Data?
Thank you so much!

Comment: How about `=SUM(Fields!Quantity.value)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped that line. It SHOULD be Quantity that's not summing up.

Comment: Is your City in the **Category Groups**? If so, are you sure that one of them doesn't have a space at the end?

Comment: Suggestion: pie charts are not the best way to display data esp. using 3d affects.  https://www.perceptualedge.com/example12.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your char properties, for ***Values*** select `Quantity` column:

[image]

And for the ***Category Groups***, select `City` column:

[image]

So you will end up with `SUM(Quantity)` for values and city for category groups:

[image]

This should fix the chart and should be displayed as one big pie:

[image]

Side note, you should ensure that the `City` values doesn't have any trailing spaces at the end so that when grouping it will group correctly.

Comment: I think your answer, @MahmoudGamal , is correct and am marking it as such. I didn't want to cloud the question with some additional details, but those details probably would have made the question more useful to the community. I don't know how else to explain it other than A) more columns were at work behind the scenes, and B) there's a data integrity issue that is being worked on that didn't allow my graph to work as advertised. Thanks!